# How do I add more polygons?

Tags: sculpt

I want to sculpt this ball but the polygons are too big, I want to add more, but I don't know how.
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Subdivide](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/subdivide.html) in edit mode may help with this too.

Answer (score 5):

When you create your primitive object you always have the possibility to change some parameters on the bottom of the *Tools* panel, if you increase *Segments* and *Rings* it will create more polygons. If you ever move your object or go in *Edit* mode, though, you won't have access to these parameters anymore.

But actually when you sculpt there's a tool called *Dyntopo* that allows you to increase the topology only on the area you sculpt with your brush, that is useful because you don't need to increase your object up to a crazy amount of polygons if you don't need details everywhere. The lower the dyntopo *Detail Size* factor is the more it will add polygons.

Anyway, even if you end up with a very high poly at the end you can come back to a lower poly with tricks like baking the normals for a low poly version of your object (in this case, before any Dyntopo, save the low-poly version).

You could also dig into the *Multiresolution* modifier, nice way to sculpt.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll look at it since i'm new to the interface, and 2.8 is kinda different.